# Problem with publishing project via Netlify using github (No url found for submodule path)

Tags: git, github, netlify

I m working on frontend-mentor projects  and simply want do publish project solution via Netlify.
My project structure is : frontendmentor-challenges / project1, project2, etc: see image here:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn9Yw.png)

My branch is clean and all repository inside main folder is clean.

When I try to publish subfolder repository project via Netlify I get following error:
[Netlify error URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0MNN.png)

And yes, when I open my github repository url,I can see active link only with main folder:
[repository link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmic0.png)

What I m doing wrong?
Any idea how to fix URL problem deploying project to Netlify

Thanks

Comment: Githublink: https://github.com/banet/Frontend_mentor-devchallenge

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved with new drag and drop feature on Netifly (you just drag your project folder in container) and you are ready to go. You don't need to think about git or github  anymore